what is the best alternative i can use in auth0 for my appilcation which uses third party cookies?
Since Third party cookies will be blocked what are the alternatives?
Solution for best auth0 solution to overcome third party cookies,
the solution i found are Custom domains and refresh tokens in auth0. I do not need to worry about the original authentication flow, but the silent authentication happens via third-party cookies hence i need an alternative

Alternatives are described at https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd
